# Refrigerator making loud clunking sound

Tags: refrigerator

My refrigerator recently started getting to warm.

We blew out the condenser coils and refrigerator section is working ok but freezer will not get below 18 degrees Fahrenheit.

Also there is  a loud clunking, rattling noise when fridge is moved sideways. This sounds like it may be  the compressor  bounding around.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for help with.  If it's the "clunking" noise that happens when you move the unit sideways, then by all means STOP doing that.  If it's the issue with not getting cold any longer, I suspect you have a low refrigerant charge.  Call a service technician to evaluate.

Comment: A large clunking sound could be many things, 
Since Refridgeration equipment is a licensed trade we can look at a few things. But with the available information it is hard to provide a proper answer.
Blew out the coils, is the fan clean and functional if it has one.  
With out a proper air flow on the condensing coils the heat exchange is limited. I ask about the fan because it can be the sound hitting something.

Answer (score 0):

A large clunking sound could be many things,
Since Refridgeration equipment is a licensed trade we can look at a few things. But with the available information it is hard to provide a proper answer.
Two long for a comment so here are a few things to check.

Blew out the coils, is the fan clean and functional if it has one.
With out a proper air flow on the condensing coils the heat exchange is limited. I ask about the fan because it can be the sound hitting something or clunking
Next I would look in the freezer section is it a frost free model? Again is the fan working, coils iced up? Usually with frost free you have to remove covers or defrost if it works for a while after defrosting it could be the fan or the defrost timer/ heater to thaw the coils.
If the above all check out we are to a pressure check.
Most refrigerators do not have a service port so one has to be added to check the charge and if needed recharge the system..
there are mechanical port / valves that can be added for under 20$ but these are questionable in my opinion but may be an option for a less expensive repair if the system just needs a recharge.